# Matlab: Detect peaks above a certain height on bar graph and label just above peak height

Tags: matlab, plot, label, bar-chart

I am trying to add labels to a bar chart with many bars. The complicating factor is that I am doing this in a loop (for hundreds of bar-charts) and want to have Matlab do the labeling automatically. Essentially, I only want to label peaks with a height above a certain threshold. One thing which should hopefully make this easier is that I simply want to label the bar with it's x-value.

Here's an illustration of how I want the label placed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you still have access to the original data, and assuming you want to label each point that's above the threshold, you should be able to do this by:

- loop over each (x, y) in data array for the chart

  - if y is bigger than the threshold

    - then call [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text.html)`(x, y, num2str(x))`

If you want to label peaks that have consecutive values all above the threshold (like around maybe 115 on your image?) with a single label, you can add some slightly more complicated logic to group those peaks together...if that's what you want, we can help you figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Dougal, the `text` function is what you want. However, there is no need to loop:

```
%# generate some data
y = poissrnd(5,20,1);
x = 1:20;
%# find where the data is above the threshold
bigIdx = y>6;

%# create a bar plot
bar(x,y)

%# add the text. The alignment setting ensures that the text
%# is directly above the bar. I add 1 here as an y-offset,
%# the ideal value may depend on your data
text(x(bigIdx),y(bigIdx)+1,num2str(x(bigIdx)),'horizontalAlignment','center')

%# you may need to make sure that the y-limit is high enough
%# so that the text is visible
ylim([0 max(y)+2])
```

[image]

Comment: This also seems like a good solution, and even may be more efficient, but I already implemented Dougal's solution and it is working well for me. I will definitely keep this in mind though.